# Limiting the size of a ZFS dataset for timemachine

Tags: server, 20.04, mount, zfs

I am trying to create a ZFS dataset with a limited size to share as a timemachine. I have managed to get the timemachine share working using netatalk but I am unable to limit the size of a zfs dataset and share it with netatalk.

I have tried `sudo zfs create -V 500GB mypool/timemachine` which does create a dataset but I cannot see it as a valid timemachine drive on the mac. I have noticed when running `zfs list` that the dataset has no mount point and I have tried `zfs mount -a` to mount it but no luck.

I don't have much on mypool at the moment as its a fresh install so if I have to start again and split the pool up then I can, but any advice on how to do this is apprciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you're creating a zvol (block storage) and *not* a dataset—due to the use of `-V`—which should be visible at `/dev/zvol/mypool/timemachine`. You can use `mkfs.XXX` to format this.

If you really want to create a *dataset* instead because you don't need a specific filesystem, leave out said `-V 500GB` above in order to create one and use `zfs set quota=500G mypool/timemachine` instead to limit its size.

https://openzfsonosx.org/wiki/Time_Machine_Backups might give you an idea how to use either storage. However, since you mentioned Netatalk above, you're likely aware of the related steps as discussed in https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/nas/netatalk_configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification, I am new to this so it all helps. I used the solution to set the quota and it worked perfectly.

Thanks for the link as well.